# Ironpython not able to calculate md5check sum for large size files

Tags: python, ironpython, md5sum

```
import hashlib
with open("file5GB.bin" , 'rb') as fd:
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    while True:
        data = fd.read(2**20)
        if not data:
            break
        md5.update(data)
    md5_local = md5.hexdigest()
    print md5_local
```

results in `MemoryError: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.`

The same code works fine with python.

Ironpython version : 2.7.5,FileSize : 5GB